# How to center align the table which has dynamic columns in a slide using apache poi ppt

Tags: apache-poi, powerpoint

We are generating a PPT file using apache poi 3.9. The table in the slide will have dynamic number of columns. How to center align the table in the generated file. Now, the margin is set using:

```java
table.setAnchor(new Rectangle(50, 60, 300, 300));
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to something vaguely recent?

Comment: Our server is running on jre7, so this is the compatible version for jre7

Comment: Nope, that's wrong! As per [the Apache POI homepage](http://poi.apache.org/), 4.0 is the first version needing Java 8, so there is nothing stopping you there from upgrading to 3.17

Comment: Even in 3.17 i dont see default api to center align a table. Please let me know if you find any. For now, i have resolved this issue, by calculating the table width and setting the left margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the table width and setting the left margin. That should fix the issue. I will check if there is any alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved by calculating the table width and setting the left margin